# Open local folder via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension that (among other things) allow the user to open a local folder when he click on a "file:///" link.

I understand that it's can't be done in JavaScript without extension. ([Open local folder from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246292/open-local-folder-from-link)) and I know that I can open the "download" folder, like this: `chrome.downloads.showDefaultFolder();`

My question is, if it possible via Chrome extension.

---

One more interesting point: In "extension" page (chrome://extensions/) in my extension section (which run from local folder) there is a link "Loaded from:" like this:

[image: screenshot]

When I click on this link the extension folder is open. I was searched the script who do this and I found this: `chrome.send('extensionSettingsShowPath', [String(extension.id)]);`

If I will understand what this line do, maybe I will know how to do this.

Comment: [showPath](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/developerPrivate#method-showPath) only shows the specified extension's path, not an arbitrary one. I think the behavior you want can be implemented via [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Windows Explorer (Windows+E) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587857/how-to-open-windows-explorer-windowse-using-javascript)

Comment: @nycynik not necessarily at all. My question is about **chrome extension**, which have more possibility to allow the code to interact with the hosting Operation System than js in the browser.