# How Can I Open My File explorer using HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently working on a project where i have made a windows 10 taskbar

as you can see in this image 
[Result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeSVA.png)

In the result I have used for chrome img tag::  **`onclick="chrome()"`**

```
        function chrome()
    {
                    window.open("https://www.google.com", "", "width=580,height=820");
    }
```

which allows me to open a new window if you click on chrome icon

#### Now I want that if I click the File Explorer icon ..

#### It should open file:///C:/ for me

And I have tried the above function (window.open();) to open file:///C:/ but it doesn't works 
is there any alternative way that I can open file explorer inside my browser or external just by clicking the img tag ????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Windows Explorer (Windows+E) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587857/how-to-open-windows-explorer-windowse-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open application with javascript pure , Because they are on the front-end side .
I have two ideas for this 
One use the `input:file` tag:

```js
<input type="file" />​
```

Two, use your local network path:

```js
window.open("file:///" + yourLocalOrNetworkPath);
```